# Outer automorphisms of direct product of finitely generated groups

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $A,B$ be finitely generated residually finite groups such that $\text{Out}(A)$ and $\text{Out}(B)$ are residually finite.

Is $\text{Out}(A \times B)$ residually finite?

Comment: Hi Michal - I got your facebook message, but I struggle to check facebook often. So I thought I would reply here. Short answer is: I do not know. Long answer: Certainly, if $A$ is infinite cyclic and $B$ does not map onto $\mathbb{Z}$ then $\operatorname{Out}(A\times B)$ is residually finite as it virtually embeds into $\operatorname{Out}(B)$. The restrictions mean that every automorphism sends $B$ to a conjugate of itself, so finding $\operatorname{Out}(A\times B)$ is easier. So perhaps dropping the restriction of "$B$ does not map onto $\mathbb{Z}$" would be a good place to start cont.

Comment: ...inued I didn't do this case in my thesis as I ran out of time! If I had the time I would approach the problem in one of two ways. Way 1: Assume that $A$ and $B$ are "fixed" by every outer automorphism. This gives you a distinguished subgroup of $\operatorname{Out}$, and one which is easy to work with. Way 2: $\operatorname{Out}(A\ast B)$ is *not* residually finite if one of $A$ or $B$ is not residually finite (assuming trivial centers). cont.

Comment: ...inued This is because you can conjugate $A$ by an element of $B$ and fix $B$, so $A$ embeds into $\operatorname{Out}(A\ast B)$. Then look at the map $\operatorname{Out}(A\ast B)\rightarrow \operatorname{Out}(A\times B)$ and try and emulate what is happening with free groups. Nick Gilbert has a paper from the 80s which tells you about $\operatorname{Out}(A\ast B)$ (or there are Russian papers of Faux Rabinovich). Finally, I would check $BS(2, 3)\times BS(2, 3)$ (or some other BS group - look up the paper *Tree actions of automorphism groups* which talks about their $\operatorname{Out}s$).

Comment: Thanks. I just realised I forgot to mention one critical assumption: both $A$ and $B$ are residually finite as well. That excludes BS(2,3). I'll look on the paper, though.

Comment: Cross-posted in mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185866/outer-automorphisms-of-direct-product-of-residually-finite-groups